# Electric current though liquid - Magnet interaction

Tags: electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics, electricity

I f a have a coil with an electric current flowing through it, and I place it inside of a magnetic field, it will move.

Now my question is, what happens if I have a droplet of liquid with an electric current flowing through it, will it also move ? If not, why not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it will move.  Here is a familiar science demonstration, the
mercury 'beating heart'  [BEATING HEART](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m6631u7d4E0)  which
shows a crude battery circuit (the mercury and the iron in a
mild acid).   When the iron touches the mercury, the battery
puts a current through the contact point, and that current
deforms the mercury because it creates a changing magnetic field.

The deformation breaks the contact, and the force on the mercury
goes away, which reestablishes electric contact... and it oscillates.

It's literally a changing magnetic field that's moving the mercury,
but the coil-in-a-field causes more of a torque effect than
a translational motion.   The application of torque to a liquid
is a difficult thing to demonstrate; how would one know that
a liquid drop was rotating?

A drop of conductive liquid in a changing magnetic field WILL transformer-couple
to that field, and generate a little loop of internal current.
The problem, then, is to see a drop become nonspherical when
a changing magnetic field excites it, and then see some indication
of axial tilt due to a nonchanging magnetic field.

Probably, this could be accomplished, with stop-action video
to record droplets in free fall.  It'll look like a bunch
of wires with a quivering raindrop falling through a magnet gap...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't see the relation between the mercerury beating heart and an applied magnetic field to a current passing through a liquid. The mercury beating heart is an electrochemical redox reaction.

Comment: Oh, the beating heart is electromechanical.  The force on the mercury is plain old magnetism; the 'redox reaction' doesn't apply force, just current that makes a crude electromagnet.

Comment: Do you think, one could split the mercury with the magnetic force ?

Comment: Yes, one can split the liquid; such force can be enough to explode a wire, or to shrink a coin (I have a US quarter that's about the diameter of a dime).

Comment: Wow ! How  did you do that ? ... and how exactley would you split the liquid ?

Comment: Coin shrinking uses fast high-current pulses <http://www.capturedlightning.com/frames/shrinker.html>  from apparatus that you wouldn't want to get close to...  As for the liquid, a  high enough applied force would make it splash instead of just quiver.